# Finding $n$th power of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Find the $A^n$ if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b \\0 & 1 &a\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ 
I tried inductive method to show $$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}1 & na & nb+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2 \\0 & 1 &na\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ 
now : My question is : Is there other method (idea ) to find $A^n$ ?
Thanks in advance.
Can the idea apply for $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b \\0 & 1 &c\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$ when $c \neq a$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b \\0 & 1 &c\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$

Write $A = I + U$, where $U^2 = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & c \end{bmatrix}$ and $U^3=0$.

$$ A^n=(I+U)^n=I+nU+{n\choose 2}U^2 =
\pmatrix{1&na&nb+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}ac\\0&1&nc\\0&0&1}$$

Answer (score 11):

If we define
$$ N=\begin{bmatrix}0&a&b\\0&0&a\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $$
then $A=I+N$, $N^3=0$, and $I$ and $N$ commute. Therefore we can use to the binomial theorem to obtain
$$ A^n=(I+N)^n=I+nN+{n\choose 2}N^2 $$
which matches your answer.

Comment: To address the edit, this method also works if the second $a$ is replaced with a $c\neq a$.

Answer (score 3):

$$A=I+aJ+bJ^2$$
where
$$J=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}.$$
Then $J^3=O$.
Now
$$A^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(aJ+bJ^2)^n
=I+n(aJ+bJ^2)+{n\choose 2}(aJ+bJ^2)^2$$
as $(aJ+bJ^2)^3=O$. But $(aJ+bJ^2)^2=a^2J^2$ so
$$A^n=I+naJ+nbJ^2+\frac{n(n-1)}2a^2J^2
=\pmatrix{1&na&nb+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2\\0&1&na\\0&0&1}.$$